# How can I run multiple Powershell commands in just one powershell windows in Java?

Tags: java, powershell

Its exceuting single command at a time but i want like this..
its from Powershell Perspective

Invoke  .\add.ps1
Enter First variable value : 12
Enter Second variable value : 13
Addition : 25

i want commands to executed one after the other from java code

Comment: I already did R&D which was required.

Comment: I already tested that one but not working getting some error

Comment: And how are supposed to know that? Hint, in such cases, you write up a question like "I have problem X. I found existing question Y. But when I try Z, I get these error messages here." (and I mean: the exact error messages). You did none of that. You told us what you need; nothing else.

Comment: thanks GhostCat ya you are right I think i should put like that only

Comment: You are welcome. Keep going!